# Сохранить конечное состояние CSS3 transition

Tags: css3, css-animation, transition

В CSS3 появилась удобная возможность делать плавный переход из одного состояния в другое - свойство `transition`. Проблема в том, что после завершения анимации элемент возращается в начальное состояние. Есть ли возможность сохранить конечное состояние анимации без использования `JavaScript`?

```css
input {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: solid #0275D8;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  transition: width 2s;
}

input:hover {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что hover'а больше нет и стиля тоже.

Скорее всего тебе надо это:

```css
input {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: solid #0275D8;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  transition: width 2s;
}

input:hover, input:focus {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<input />
```

Если нужно именно оставить после hover'а, то можно попытаться использовать keyframes:

```css
input {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: solid #0275D8;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  animation: enlarge-once 2s linear 1 forwards paused;
}

input:hover, input:focus {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes enlarge-once {
  0% { width: 0.2em; }
  100% { width: 20em; }
}
```

```html
<input />
```